# heatmap.2 colors really wonky

Tags: r, visualization, heatmap

Does anyone know why my heatmap.2 result has weird colors - the turquoise doesn't belong in my red/black/green palette? It appears the turquoise refers to information based on sample clustering (the row dendrogram which I "FALSE"-ed out), and not based on feature clustering. What's up with this?

I am using gplots, RBrewerColor and heatmap.2() method.

Code:

```
temp <- t(iris[,1:4])
sampleLabels.c <- as.character(iris[,5])
sampleLabels.c[sampleLabels.c=="setosa"] <- "red"
sampleLabels.c[sampleLabels.c=="versicolor"] <- "orange"
sampleLabels.c[sampleLabels.c=="virginica"] <- "green"

# Sort on max difference
t.min <-apply(temp, 1, min)
t.max <- apply(temp, 1, max)
temp <- temp[order(t.max-t.min, decreasing=TRUE),]
# cluster on correlation
hc <- hclust(as.dist(1 - cor(temp)), method="average")
png("iris.png", 1000, 1000)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
heatmap.2(as.matrix(temp),
      Rowv=FALSE,
      Colv=as.dendrogram(hc),
      dendrogram="column",
      col=greenred(10),
      labRow="", labCol="", key=TRUE,
      ColSideColors=sampleLabels.c)
legend("left",
   legend=c("Setosa", "Versicolor", "Virginica"),
   col=c("red", "orange", "green"),
   lty=1, lwd=2)
dev.off()
```

Here is the image that generates from the code (above).

[image]
Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for "cyan" in `?heatmap.2` gives:

> trace=c("column","row","both","none"),
>                   tracecol="cyan" ...
>   ...
>
> `trace`: character string indicating whether a solid "trace" line
>             should be drawn across 'row's or down 'column's, 'both' or
>             'none'.  The distance of the line from the center of each
>             color-cell is proportional to the size of the measurement.
>             Defaults to 'column'.

Try setting `trace="none"` ... ?

Comment: You are FANTASTIC! Thank you so much! I never would have thought to search for "cyan" in the help page!